# Access: Query Multiple field records to columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS-Access, I have the following table that has repeated fields (SpecialtyCodes) that I want to to display these as columns. Its Kind of a crosstab, but Access needs a value different field. IDName, would be my row heading field, and SpecialtyCode would be my column heading field, but I can't select the same field for field.

Having a hard time trying to explain what I'm trying to accomplish, so I am showing an example. I know this isn't a normalized table, but I am getting data from a report to put into a table.

Example table:

```
IDName     SpecialtyCode
A1         11   
A1         23  
A1         154    
A2         44  
A2         88  
A3         05
```

Example output:

```
IDName     SpecialtyCode   SpecialtyCode   SpecialtyCode
A1         11              23              154
A2         44              88
A3         05
```

Comment: If you publish the schema you will have a better chance of someone writing a query for you.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a great way to do this that I know of. Here's what I'd do:

Start by ranking your entries.

```
SELECT tb.IdName, tb.specialtyCode, 
     (SELECT COUNT(tbi.specialtyCode) FROM Table1 AS tbi WHERE tbi.IdName = tb.IdName 
      AND tbi.specialtyCode >= tb.specialtyCode) AS rank
FROM Table1 AS tb
```

Next, you can nest this query, and use `IIF` to put each entry in a different column.

```
SELECT tbo.IdName, 
MAX(IIF(tbo.rank = 1, tbo.specialtyCode, "")) AS firstsc,
MAX(IIF(tbo.rank = 2, tbo.specialtyCode, "")) AS secondsc,
MAX(IIF(tbo.rank = 3, tbo.specialtyCode, "")) AS thirdsc
FROM
     (SELECT tb.IdName, tb.specialtyCode, 
          (SELECT COUNT(tbi.specialtyCode) FROM Table1 AS tbi WHERE 
           tbi.IdName = tb.IdName AND tbi.specialtyCode >= tb.specialtyCode) 
           AS rank
      FROM Table1 AS tb) AS tbo
GROUP BY tbo.IdName
```